# Is it possible to set an image from URL on android canvas that should support all devices screen sizes?

Tags: android

I am trying to set an image from url on canvas and this image should be supported by all the devices screens, is it possible in android to do this without nine-patch image?

Also I can't set different dimensions image for different screen sizes from drawable resources because I am fetching the image from URL.

Answer (score 0):

One option I can suggest u,

```
URL url = new URL(urlString); //Convert url string to url object.
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
Bitmap myImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
Bitmap resizedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImageBitmap, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);
// dstWidth & dstHeight are the needed size of image.
```

And regarding the screen size, u can get it by overriding the `onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)` method of View class where w & h are current width and height of screen.